# Can't Remove a Menu in Python Add-in

Tags: python, arcmap, python-addin

I have a Python add-in with a good amount of buttons and menus. I'm trying to remove a menu using the addin_assistant, but the menu isn't being removed from config.xml. I've tried removing the add-in in ArcMap and re-adding it, but that didn't help.

The process I'm doing:

1. Open the Python Add-in Wizard, browse to my add-in folder.
2. Find the menu. Right click and Remove.
3. Save. Click OK for the backup warning message.
4. `The config.xml` document date is modified automatically by saving.
5. Open the XML and see that the menu is not removed.

**Quick thoughts:**
I've tried restarting my computer.
I've removed buttons successfully.
I can't remake the add-in every time I want to remove a menu.
*Customize Mode -> Delete* for the menu (in ArcMap) isn't feasible because this add-in will be shared with hundreds of users.

Any thoughts? Please let me know if you need more info.

**Edit:**

I've copied the contents of my add in folder to a different folder. I tried removing the menu the way I previously described and it didn't work.

I edited the XML in Notepad++ to manually remove the menu and ran the makeaddin.py file, then removed and re-added the add-in in ArcMap. This didn't remove the menu.

Double clicking and installing the esri addin file worked to remove the menu since I've edited the XML, but now when I try to access the add-in directory using the add-in assistant I get an error window that says:

*Error initializing Add-In*

*add-in name.menu_remove*  (which was the name of the menu ID).

It seems that the addin_assistant is expecting to find menu, but since it was removed in XML it's throwing an error.

**Edit 2**

I didn't fully delete all of the required lines in XML. The error thrown above no longer appears. I had to delete both the Menu caption for the menu category and the Menu refID that referenced my menus ID (menu_remove).

Editing the XML works well enough to consider this answered. Esri believes the issue is a bug or limitation with the python addin wizard. I'll add that info when I receive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a two-part question, but here we go:

1. If you are *absolutely certain* you are doing the process you claim to the letter and the menu item is still not being deleted from the configuration XML, you may need to go into the `.XML` file and delete the menu by hand in a text editor like Notepad++. You may want to file an issue with Esri support, there may be a bug in the Python add-in wizard. I tried adding/removing menus with various item types and I had no problem, so you may need to share the add-in with Esri.
2. There is [a documented way to deploy add-ins via a shared network folder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p0000001m000000) so every time you update the `.esriaddin` file usrs that are configured to use the add-in will see your updates.

Comment: I'm certain that I'm doing the process correctly. I'm hesitant to edit the .xml, but if ESRI support can't find anything I will do that. Also, I will be using that deployment method you linked. Distributed was a bad word choice.

Comment: Worst case scenario: [the Add-In Wizard source is available online](https://github.com/jasonbot/addin-wizard). It's a simple wxPython application, should be fairly easily hackable.